# How to get all columns which are nearly as long as the maximum allowed size

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-metadata

Is it possible to get all columns (varchar2, char, nvarchar2), where the data is as long (or nearly as long - 2 characters less) than the allowed maximum size of the column in an Oracle Database?

With the following statement, I get the maximum allowed size for each column:

```
select table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length 
from user_tab_columns 
where data_type in ('VARCHAR2', 'CHAR', 'NVARCHAR2') 
order by data_type;
```

Now I want to find every column `where max(length(column))+2 >= data_length`

For example:

The output of my statement is following:

```
TableA  | ColumnA |  VARCHAR2 |  30
TableA  | ColumnB |  VARCHAR2 |  30
TableB  | ColumnA |  VARCHAR2 |  50
TableB  | ColumnB |  VARCHAR2 |  50
```

Now I have to run

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(ColumnA)) FROM TableA;
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(ColumnB)) FROM TableA;
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(ColumnA)) FROM TableB;
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(ColumnB)) FROM TableB;
```

with following results:

- 20 (is not important, because maximum allowed length is 30)
- 30 **(is important, because maximum allowed length is 30)**
- 30 (is not important, because maximum allowed length is 50)
- 50 **(is important, because maximum allowed length is 50)**

Is this possible to find all of them with a script or a statement?

Comment: Oh yeah, now it makes plain sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible with PL/SQL:

1. make a `FOR LOOP` on your columns,
2. print output of the max data length; you can add your comparison in the prepared statement `v_qry`:

   ```
   declare
     v_qry varchar2(4000) := '';
     v_res number;
   begin
     for x in (
       select table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length 
         from user_tab_columns 
        where data_type in ('VARCHAR2', 'CHAR', 'NVARCHAR2') 
      order by data_type
     ) loop
        -- prepare your statement
        v_qry := 'select  MAX(LENGTH('||x.column_name||')) FROM '||x.table_name||' ';
        -- execute
        execute immediate v_qry into v_res;
        -- print result
       dbms_output.put_line('in:'||x.table_name||'.' ||x.column_name||':'||v_res||':compared to:'|| x.data_length);
     end loop;
   end;
   /
   ```

**NB:** it can take time depending on your tables sizes

With on of my tables (`MY`) it gives:

```
in:MY.C_UTI_MAJ:6:compared to:6
in:MY.C_UTI_CRE:6:compared to:6
in:MY.C_TYP_PARAM:20:compared to:20
in:MY.PARAM:16:compared to:20
in:MY.DESCRIPTION:245:compared to:255
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the encoding you are using in your database.

For example, if you are using UTF8 (AL32UTF8: 4 bytes for one char) you should compare results of `LENGTH()` with the column `CHAR_LENGTH` in `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`, and results of `LENGTHB()` with `DATA_LENGTH` column in  `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`.

And consider too that `CHAR` data type fields will always be padded with spaces: so `LENGHT()` will give you the length defined for datatype (you can use `RTRIM()` before `LENGTH()` ).